# Is there a better way to create variables with a certain correlation and one of them is heteroskedastic?

Tags: r, regression, correlation, monte-carlo, heteroscedasticity

**My goal is to generate two variable which are correlated and one of them is heteroscedastic with regards to an grouping variable.**

To create two variables with a desired correlation the common way to go is to use the cholesky decomposition. I additionally used the residuals of the orthogonal projection and standardized the variables up front to make sure the correlation stays at the desired value.

To introduce heteroscedasticity to one of the variables i tried the following:

1. I did the cholesky decomposition for $u=(u_1,u_2), \ q[i] =
       c(1,1.01,1.02,1.03,...)$

   $Var(u) = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & \rho\cdot q[i] \\ \rho\cdot q[i] &
   q[i]^2 \end{pmatrix}$

   The reason why I choose this covariance matrix is that while the
   variance of $u_2$ increases with $q[i]$ the correlation stays at the
   desired value $\rho$.

   But this does obviously not introduce heteroscedasticity to $u_2$....
2. A second attempt was to decomposed both variables $u_1,u_2$ with sample size n into two
   parts each of length $\frac{1}{2}\cdot n$: $\ u_1 = (u_{1.1},u_{1.2}), u_2 =
   (u_{2.1},u_{2.2})$.     Now i did the cholesky decomposition for

   $Var(u) = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & \rho & \rho\sqrt{q[i]} \\ 0 & 1 &
   \rho & \rho\sqrt{q[i]} \\ \rho & \rho & 1 & 0 \\ \rho\sqrt{q[i]} &
   \rho\sqrt{q[i]} & 0 & q[i] \end{pmatrix}$

   After I generated the four variables I
   merged $u_{1.1},u_{1.2}$ back to one $n\times 1$ vector. Analogous
   for $u_2$. Testing the outcome yields that the heteroscedasticity is now where it   should be as the variance of $u_{2.2}$ increases with $q[i]$. But the correlation vanishes as
   $q[i]$ increases because the variance of $u_2$ increases more
   rapidly then the covariance between $u_1$ and $u_2$
3. A third attempt which i end up doing was to just multiply $u_2$ with
   a dummy-variable

   $z_2 =\begin{cases}   1\\   q[i] \end{cases}$

   This approach does work for
   small values of $q[i]$ (as my graphic shows) but as soon as $q[i]$ is
   large enough it dominates the nominator and denominator of the
   correlation coefficient such that the conditional variance
   (depending on the value of $z_2$) does no longer increase in $q[i]$.

Here is my code for case (3):

```
q     <- seq(1.01,10,0.1)
n         <- 100
rho   <- 0.5
sd_u1     <- numeric(0)
sd_u2.1   <- numeric(0)
sd_u2.2   <- numeric(0)
cor_u1_u2 <- numeric(0)


for(i in 1:length(q)){
u1      <- rnorm(n,0,1)
u1      <- ( u1 - mean(u1) )/sd(u1)
u2      <- rnorm(n,0,1)
z2      <- c(rep(1,0.5*n),rep(q[i],0.5*n))
u2      <- u2*z2
u2      <- as.vector( ( diag(n) - u1%*%solve(t(u1)%*%u1)%*%t(u1) ) %*% u2 )
u2      <- ( u2 - mean(u2) )/sd(u2)
z       <- cbind(u1, rho*u1+sqrt(1-rho^2)*u2) 
sd_u1[i]      <- sd(z[,1])
sd_u2.1[i]    <- sd(z[,2][1:(0.5*n)])
sd_u2.2[i]    <- sd(z[,2][(0.5*n+1):n])
cor_u1_u2[i]  <- cor(z[,1],z[,2])
}
par(mfrow=c(3,1))
plot(q,sd_u1, type="l")
plot(q,sd_u2.1, type="l", ylim=c(0,2))
lines(q,sd_u2.2,col="red")
plot(q,cor_u1_u2, type="l")
```

[image]

Comment: It would help to explain your problem in English and mathematical terms, rather than wholly as an `R` program. There are several reasons for this, including (1) the program might not be doing what you intend, (2) it would help readers avoid having to work through code to understand the question, and (3) in the course of having to explain the circumstances clearly, you might arrive at a solution yourself.

Comment: i edited a short description on top of the main article

Comment: Thanks. I find the notation mysterious: what is the relationship between $u$ and the $q[i]$? Obviously there are many $q[i]$, so how is it possible to specify correlations with only a two by two matrix? If you intend this as a sequence of matrices, then you have only specified a small part of the full covariance matrix (blocks along the diagonal). What should the off-diagonal blocks contain?  Perhaps you could back up a little and tell us what exactly you mean by a "variable" and "heteroscedastic with respect to a grouping variable." What is your model for heteroscedasticity?

Comment: Sorry about my crappy notation. By a variable I mean a random variable. In this case I got n realisations of this particular random variable. Since I got two of them I design a 2x2 covariance matrix. The relationship between $u$ and $q[i]$ is that I use a sequence $q[i]$ to increase the variance of one part of $u$ such that it couses heteroscedasitcity. Since both variables have zero mean I can describe the correlationmatrix in this way because $E(uu') = I_2$ With L equal to the cholesky decomposition ill get $E(Luu'L') = LI_2 L' = Q$ with Q the desired covariance matrix-

Comment: My model is fairly simple and will look like: $y_1 = \beta_0 + \beta_1 z_2 + u_1$ and $y_2 = \alpha_0 + \alpha_1 z_2 + u_2$

Comment: Let's check that I understand, because many interpretations still seem possible. Do you wish to generate a *sequence* of vector-valued variables $(U_i,V_i)$ such that (1) Var$(V_i)=q_i$ (with $q_i$ predetermined) and (2) the correlation coefficient of the *realized* values $(u_i,v_i)$ equals $\rho$?  (Please notice the distinction between the random variables and their realizations in this description.) And perhaps you want $V_i/q_i$ and $U_i$ all to be identically distributed? Maybe you only want the *expectation* of the correlation coefficient of $(u_i,v_i),i=1,\ldots,n$ to equal $\rho$?

Comment: I understand your confusion. Since this setup is for a monte carlo simulation (which i did not say)  everything i do relates to realized values. This said the numerical propertys of $(u_i,v_i)$ are important. This means that if i calculate the correlation between $u_i$ and $v_i$ it should be $\rho$. But $v_i$ is not supposed to be identically distributed. I want to split $v_i$ into two parts each having a different variance. The variance of the first part of $v_i$ is supposed to be fixed and the variance of the other part is supposed to depend on $q_i$.

Comment: The var-cov-matrix is of dimension 2x2 because the cholesky decomposition can be used to create two vectors $(u_i,v_i)$ of dimension $n\times 1$ with a certain correlation $\rho$

Comment: i kinda did it. ill post it later on. but as always it did not quite solve my problem^^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ruscio and Kaczetow (2008) proposed a method for inducing an exact correlation into two random variables with arbitrary distributions. Both variables can be sampled from existing empirical distributions, and the marginal distributions will reflect these distributions.

They have an accompanying R code which works (I used it a couple of times). As some minor typing errors in the original code had to be corrected: [here](https://gist.github.com/4045717)'s a cleaned version.

Ruscio, J., & Kaczetow, W. (2008). Simulating Multivariate Nonnormal Data Using an Iterative Algorithm. Multivariate Behavioral Research, 43(3), 355–381. [doi:10.1080/00273170802285693](http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/00273170802285693)

Comment: I hope that is an answer to the question (as it is not entirely clear to me as well ...)

Comment: sry i was at my moms :) yes this was very helpfull though i did it in a different way. as i said i was looking for a way to generate two variables with a certain correlation from which one is heteroscedastic. one covariance-matrix which does the job is the following: $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & \rho & rho[l]*\sqrt{q[i]} \\ 0 & 1 & \rho & \rho*\sqrt{2}*\sqrt{1+q[i]}-\rho \\ \rho & \rho & 1 & 0 \\ \rho*\sqrt{q[i]} & \rho*\sqrt{2}*\sqrt{1+q[i]}-\rho & 0 & q[i] \end{pmatrix}$

Comment: Before I was using the Cholesky-Decomposition to get the desired weights but I find it much easier to use the Singular Value Decomposition instead. Though this matrix does control the correlation in each group it tends to get larger in the group $u_{1.2},u_{2.2}$ for a certain $\rho$ if $q[i]$ increases. If $\rho$ reaches 0.5 the overall correlation does does decrease too if $q[i]$ increases. I know that my descriptions are rather cryptic and im very sorry about that. If someone is really interestend in my simulation study i would really like to explained it in more detial perhaps via chat :)